# Downloading files from the server to the local machine in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, download

In my application I have a requirement where the client/user needs to download video files from the server to their local machine.

I have to do this using ASP .NET - can anyone help me by providing some ideas, coding to implement this.

Comment: What specific problems are you having? (You really need to give us more to go on.)

Answer (score 0):

Rick Strahl has a short sample that does exactly this...In really comes down to setting the correct Response headers and streaming the file to the user...

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/76293.aspx